# Prevent Window close if it forced via Windows taskbar -> Close

Tags: java, swing

How can I detect the `java window closing` if it was forced by clicking on `windows taskbar -> close window`?

[image: Example]

I've found that the window to close receives the `WINDOW_CLOSING` event which is possible to process by adding `windowListener`. But in this case window would being closed anyway. Is there any way to prevent the window closing?

Comment: *"Is there any way to prevent the window closing?"*  I sure hope not.  When I (as a user) tell an app. to close, I expect it to do so.  Otherwise I'd kill it through the task manager and uninstall it.

Comment: From this point of view, my question sounds really scary. But I need this, because on close, the hard business process is running, and window should being shown while it runs. It is easy to detect `Alt + F4` and change the Windows `window decorations` by own, so I hope there is any way to resolve this issue as well.

Comment: well im sorry to scatter your hope but not only can you prevent windows from being closen you can also prevent your whole process from being terminated by any taskmanager, only the kernel itself may force your threads to stop (by discarding any further execution-cycles and removing your code from the pipeline) - but thats very bad practise and will most likely trigger antivirus-software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default close operation to [`DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE) and ask the user for a confirmation instead. It's a pretty common practice even if you want to close the frame through the X button, key combination (i.e.: <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>) or any method to close a window:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Welcome!");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you really want to exit?");
        if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            e.getWindow().dispose();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Good solution. But is there any method which is called before `windowClosing`, after pressing on `TaskBar->Close`?

Comment: Hmmm... No that I know, because closing events are processed once they actually happened. Playing with `windowActivated()` and `windowDeactivated()` methods doesn't suit the requirements either I think. You say in a comment that you figured out how to do what you need when `ALT+F4` is pressed. Can't you do the same on `windowClosing()` implementation?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent window closing you should call

```
 setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)
```

on your JFrame instance and then implement your alternative closing procedure via windowListener.