# Check what triggered WindowClosing event

Tags: java, swing, events, jframe

Is there a way to see what exactly triggered WindowClosing event in a JFrame? At the moment getSource(), it seems to only be returning the JFrame:

```
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "event source: " + e.getSource(), "Test", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
      methodA();
            }
```

I want to know this due to the method dispose() triggering a WindowClosing event. So if a button is clicked which invokes methodA() and then dispose(), dispose() triggers a closing event which is defined to call methodA() as well. This causes methodA() to be called twice and I don't want that.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == confirmButton) {
            methodA();
            dispose(); //this will trigger window closing and call methodA() again

        }
    }
```

So the way I want to solve the problem is to check if a specific button named "Confirm" is the one that triggered the closing event. Then I wouldn't want to invoke methodA() so that it's not calledtwice.

If this is impossible, can I at least check whether the close (X) button in the frame is the one that invoked the window closing event?

Thanks

Comment: `//this will trigger window closing and call methodA() again` Set a boolean flag `alreadyDoneMethodA` and check for it being false before calling `methodA`, then set it true when done.

Comment: @AndrewThompson hm, ok didn't think of that. I will try that if all else fails. Is there no way to check which button invoked the event, though?

Comment: *"Is there no way to check which button invoked the event, though?"*  You might create a stack trace and iterate the elements of the trace to see the code lines hit before arriving there.  But that would be a hack.. *"didn't think of that. I will try that if all else fails."*  You seem like you want to investigate the hacks before doing it the way it might be done in dozens of other programs.

Answer (score 3):

> *I want to know this due to the method dispose() triggering a WindowClosing event. So if a button is clicked which invokes methodA()
>   and then dispose(), dispose() triggers a closing event which is
>   defined to call methodA() as well. This causes methodA() to be called
>   twice and I don't want that.*

IMHO there's a design mistake here related to the responsibility of each component in the sense that `Close` button should just do what it is expected to do: close the frame. Or even better dispatch a [`WINDOW_CLOSING`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowEvent.html#WINDOW_CLOSING) event and let the `WindowListener` do whatever it has to be done.

If you need to be sure that `methodA()` is called *before* close the top-level container (window) then the `WindowListener` sounds like the right candidate to call that method. I'd set the default close operation to [`DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE) and let the listener dispose the window if and only if the necessary conditions are met.

See this approach exemplified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26180326/1795530) and also consider the following snippet:

```
JButton closeButton = new JButton("Close");
closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent((JButton)e.getSource());
        window.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(window, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
    }
});

...

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        // Call methodA() here.
        // If all went ok then dispose the window, otherwise log the 
        // errors/exceptions and notify the user that something went wrong.
        e.getWindow().dispose();
    }
});
```